# How to create a bookmark that is a URL in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

In InDesign, how do I create a bookmark (i.e., a bookmark that will be exported to a PDF file) that is a hyperlink to a URL?

Comment: What does the documentation with InDesign say? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Once I have a hyperlink created, how do I include it as a bookmark when exported to a PDF file? I am running InDesign CS5.5. I have tried selected the `Bookmarks` and `Hyperlinks` under the `Include` box in the `Export Adobe PDF` window, but this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the easiest thing to find in InDesign. The whole issue of interactive elements and hyperlinks has been in a state of flux through the last couple of versions. The instructions that follow are for CS5 or 5.5, and should hold good for CS4:

Open the Hyperlinks panel: Window > Automation > Hyperlinks

Highlight the text you wish to make your bookmark.

From the panel flyout menu select either "New Hyperlink" if your text is not a URL, or "New Hyperlink from URL" if your text is the URL. (Note: Do *not* choose "New Hyperlink Destination", which places a named anchor to which an internal hyperlink can refer.)

If you have a number of URLs scattered throughout the document, the flyout menu option "Convert URLs to Hyperlinks" will do them all in one swoop.

Answer (score 1):

You include the Bookmark by going to File>Export and choose PDF(Interactive) and Choose the interactive options.

Or you can choose File>Export PDF (Print) and change to Acrobat 5 compatibility, the Bookmark and Hyperlink is now available to tick.

You create bookmarks by using the Window>Interactive>Bookmarks or you can make a Hyperlink by going to Window>Interactive>Hyperlinks.

Note that most urls written with www. or http or https etc. will automatically be linked in Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party plugins for creating a bookmark in InDesign.
BrowsePlus InDesign Plugin is a web browser InDesign which allow you to manage bookmarks,save and edit bookmarks, watch videos, multiple tabs, check email, simply drag & drop images within InDesign.
http://metadesignsolutions.com/products/browseplus.php

Comment: This is relevant, but appears to be undisclosed advertising.